# Get friend details using go viral , ios and as well as android

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I get the details of my friends using go viral , both ios and androiod..

As of now I am working on ios ,

started following the following link

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/goviral-ane-android.html.html

Comment: I tried for both android and ios , Currently i am stuck with android . I am getting an error which says , current platform is not supported .

Comment: It was mentioned in the blog as well . that android is not supported

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is a bit late but here goes:

I tried the `GoViral` code as well and yes I kept getting the same error. Then I realised that I was running the thing on my Windows Laptop and not on an Android Device. So I loaded it onto my Android Device and still got the same message. Then I realised that I had included the `.swc` file but not the `.ane` file. I added the `.ane` for Android and it ran on my Android device. OK so I can send e-mails with attachements. I still cant access facebook but this is DEFINITELY to do with the way that I have set up my Facebook App on Facebook and nothing to do with the `GoViral` code.